# Undefined method m when using SimpleDelegator in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was barking up the wrong tree with my original answer - I still have the problem but the plot thickens

I'm upgrading a Ruby 1.8.7/ Rails 3.0.20 project to Ruby 2.1.2 /Rails 4.1.8

In the code I have a class which delegates a number of instance methods.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :subscription
  delegate :trial?, :payg? :to => :subscription

end
```

I have a decorator

```
class AccountOverview < SimpleDelegator
def self.for(account)
  new(account)
end

def description
  if payg?
    'Pay As You Go'
  elsif trial?
    'Free Trial'
  else
    'Subscription'
  end
end
end
```

Accessing the decorator from view gives the error message:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `m' for ):

I hunted for an extraneous m, but can't find one.

I had thought that it was using the decorator ok for methods that didn't include delegated methods and that by defining the delegated functions within the class stopped the error:

```
def payg?
  subscription.payg?
end

def trial?
  subscription.trial?
end
```

However, it was not the case. What I was seeing was that a second attempt to render the view succeeds. But if I restart the server I get the error again.

I've tried the approach of instantiating SimpleDelegator as suggested, rather than deriving from it, and found that I could not access the methods in the original class.

Try this in the rails console:

```
class Test1
  def testing
    puts 'hi'
  end
end

class Test2
  def initialize(test)
    SimpleDelegator.new(test)
    end
  def testing2
    puts 'hello'
  end
end

t = Test1.new
t.testing
hi
  => nil 

h = SimpleDelegator.new(t)

h.testing
hi
  => nil 

h = Test2.new(t)
h.testing
NoMethodError: undefined method `testing' for #<Test2:0x007fbea15d27a0>
```

But if instead I use

```
2.1.2 :008 >  class Test2 < SimpleDelegator
2.1.2 :009?>   def testing2
2.1.2 :010?>     puts 'hello'
2.1.2 :011?>     end
2.1.2 :012?>   end
 => :testing2 
2.1.2 :013 > h = Test2.new(t)
 => #<Test1:0x007fee090afc90> 
2.1.2 :014 > h.testing
hi
 => nil 
2.1.2 :015 > h.testing2
hello
 => nil
```

Also, I have found that the code that fails rendering in the view works in the console ( deriving from SimpleDelegator ):

```
a = Account.last

c = AccountOverview.new(a)

c.description
 => "Free Trial"
```

Reduced the classes to the very simplest

```
class AccountOverview < SimpleDelegator
def self.for(account)
  new(account)
end

def description
    'Pay As You Go'
end


class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Still seeing the same error referring to missing method m

Created a brand new rails 4  project and added the same code and ran against the same db - this worked with no errors, so its something in my legacy setup.

Have given up and removed SimpleDelegator from the code and just used delegate to map the required functions to an instance variable for the base object and its now working. But not very satisfying.

```
class AccountOverview

  delegate :payg?, :trial? :to => :@account

  def initialize(account)
    @account = account
  end

  def description
    if payg?
      'Pay As You Go'
    elsif trial?
      'Free Trial'
    else
      'Subscription'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I think it's because you're subclassing from `SimpleDelegator` and then overwriting the `initialize` method without calling super. [The docs show an example](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/SimpleDelegator.html) that doesn't use subclassing, and in the comments they show a way to do it without overwriting the `initialize` method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385796/has-ruby-2-0-changed-the-behaviour-of-simpledelegator there were some changes in ruby 2.0 see the link above

Comment: AfDev - that one refers to protected methods - not the case in this instance. Also it names the missing method, whereas I get this mysterious missing method 'm'

Comment: diego.greyrobot - thanks for the quick response but I can't see where I'm overwriting the initialize method. (unless 'for' is an alias for initialize?) I thought I was calling the standard initializer with the .new in the 'for' method? Odd that it would work happily in the earlier versions if that were the case?